# How we sleep. Who are we?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, video-games

> Our 1st member likes to sleep near fireplace.
>
> Our 2nd member likes to sleep after a drink of water.
>
> Our 3rd member likes to sleep on a steel bed.
>
> Our 4th member likes to sleep after exercising.
>
> Our 5th member likes to sleep with a ghost.
>
> Our 6th member likes to sleep on the ground.
>
> Our 7th member likes to sleep with a dragon.
>
> Our 8th member likes to sleep in complete darkness.

Who are we?

Subtle hint:

> Someone say we're foxes. Someone say we're dogs. Someone say we're cats. Someone say we're rabbits.

Comment: Ha! I shared this riddle to many people in this Halloween's party, and only few people got it. I gave some hints, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are

> the evolutions of **Eevee** from the Pokémon franchise

and you sleep where

> your type trumps the environment according to the [Type matchups](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Type#Type_chart) of the video games.

---

Our 1st member likes to sleep near fireplace.

> **Vaporeon**, because *Water* beats *Fire*

Our 2nd member likes to sleep after a drink of water.

> **Jolteon**, because *Electric* beats *Water*

Our 3rd member likes to sleep on a steel bed.

> **Flareon**, because *Fire* beats *Steel*

Our 4th member likes to sleep after exercising.

> **Espeon**, because *Psychic* beats *Fighting*

Our 5th member likes to sleep with a ghost.

> **Umbreon**, because *Dark* beats *Ghost*

Our 6th member likes to sleep on the ground.

> **Leafeon**, because *Grass* beats *Ground*

Our 7th member likes to sleep with a dragon.

> **Glaceon**, because *Ice* beats *Dragon*

Our 8th member likes to sleep in complete darkness.

> **Sylveon**, because *Fairy* beats *Dark*

Hint:

> All Eeveelutions resemble a furry mammal to at least some degree.

Comment: Incidentally, rot13(gurl ner yvfgrq va Angvbany 'Qrk beqre)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like:

> Pokemons: fire, water, steel, fight, ghost, ground, dragon, dark.
>
>  I was puzzled by "sleep with". But after seeing "sleep with a dragon", the only way it makes sense is:
>
>  "We" are the eight Gym Leaders!
>
>
>  ... although in none of the Pokemon games the eight Gym Leaders form that combination.

also:

> foxes, dogs, cats, rabbits might all refer to Pikachu (because in the old GB times it was difficult to tell exactly which animal it was), or there are different Pokemons who originate from these animals. Not quite the Gym Leaders, though.

However, this answer is not relevant to Halloween's party...

Comment: That's what I thought, too, but I realized (as you did) that no combination fit the implied rot13(glcrf gung rnpu genvare jbhyq fcrpvnyvmr va).

Comment: Ah... anyway I was close (:

Comment: And by the way, I didn't even know that rot13(Rrirr unf rvtug ribyhgvbaf abj... vg jnf bayl guerr jura V cynlrq ^^|)

Comment: rot13(Nyzbfg gjragl lrnef va naq V'z oneryl xrrcvat hc!)